# Change position of glossary title

Tags: positioning, titles, glossaries

I am a total beginner with LaTeX and I can't find a way to solve the following problem. I have a glossary which I have printed in two columns  by adding the code that I have included at the end. The problem is that the title of the glossary appears included in the first column. What I would like is that the title stays out, and the two column format begins after the title is printed. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfirst=true,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{multicol}

\let\glsaltpl\glsuseri
\let\glsing\glsuserii

%%Formatos para la lista de acrónimos
\newglossarystyle{EstiloGlosario}{%
\glossarystyle{listgroup}% Estilo base
%Estilo de las entradas: Entrada en negrita, descripcion normal
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\item[]{\bf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}}\;\;\;\relax
\space{\footnotesize ##3}% Description,
{,}
{\footnotesize ##5}
% Page list
\vspace{-0.2mm}% end of row
}%
%Cabecera con regla debajo de la letra inicial
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}\item[{\:}{\:}{\Large        \glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]\setlength{\itemsep}{-2.5mm}
\item[\rule{3cm}{0.02 cm}]\setlength{\itemsep}{-0mm}}
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \printglossary[type=main,style=EstiloGlosario]
    \newpage
    \end{multicols}

    \newglossaryentry{ppm}{name=ppm,description={parts per million}} The units are expressed in \gls{ppm}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In particular it's important to state what package you're using for the glossary.

Answer (score 5):

Your example code produces errors, so I used a simplified document to illustrate the procedure. You can achieve what you want by redefining `\glossarysection` to write the title using `\chapter*` and then go into two-column mode, and `\glossarypostamble` to return to one-column mode; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfirst=true,acronym,section=chapter]{glossaries}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{%
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\chapter*{#2}]
  \setlength\glsdescwidth{0.6\linewidth}%
  \glossarymark{\glossarytoctitle}%
}
\renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{EstiloGlosario}{%
\glossarystyle{listgroup}}

\newglossaryentry{ppm}{name=ppm,description={parts per million}} 
\newglossaryentry{ppb}{name=ppb,description={parts per billion}} 

\begin{document}

The units are expressed in \gls{ppm}.
The units are expressed in \gls{ppb}.

\printglossary[type=main,style=EstiloGlosario]

\end{document}
```

The resulting glossary:

[image]

If you're not interested in balanced columns, you could use `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` instead of the `multicols` environment:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{%
  \twocolumn\chapter*{#2}
  \setlength\glsdescwidth{0.6\linewidth}%
  \glossarymark{\glossarytoctitle}%
}
\renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\onecolumn}
```

Comment: Also `\twocolumn` accepts an optional argument that's typeset in onecolumn mode.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but when I tried `\twocolumn[\chapter*{#2}]`, I got a `! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.` error.

Comment: A good reason for choosing `multicols`. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! it worked like a charm! :)